# Hide a CDialogImpl dialog when user cancels

Tags: c++, windows, dialog, atl, wtl

Using a [`CDialogImpl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79bke8xf.aspx) derived class as a dialog-based WTL/ATL app, I want to hide the main window when the user clicks the upper right "X" button (or presses <kbd>Esc</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>).

Currently the "X" closes the dialog and ends the application.

[image]

I want to change this behaviour and only **hide the dialog box instead of closing it**. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if ATL/WTL provides some wrapper for this but in WinAPI, the function you are looking for is [ShowWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633548%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which you would invoke as so:

```
ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_HIDE);
```

If you want this to happen when the application is closed, the message you need to handle is [WM_CLOSE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632617%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

After a quick search, MSDN reveals [CWindow::ShowWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/40zhehxa%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which is the wrapper I mentioned earlier.